# Javascript convert string to alt shortcut key

Tags: javascript, events, keycode, alt

In JS I might have this shortcut to trigger an event:

```
alt + s
```

I have `s` from an option. How do I convert the `s` to the correct number that represent the letter?

In my code I will have something like this, but change the 98 to function that generates the number from a function, with string as input.

```
if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 98) {
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this but it gives the wrong key code:

```
var _stringToKey = function() {
    string = '{{key}}';
    return parseInt( string.charCodeAt(0) );
 }
```

{{key}} is replaced by a letter from PHP.

**Sidenote**
I don't want to rely on yet another JS plugin.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to convert string to key code except manual mapping. I would suggest you to accept `s` as key code, then you won't need such conversion.

Comment: Can you give little more description or code?

Comment: @Rajesh I updated my code now with a not so working example.

Comment: @hindmost How does that solution look like? Can I use "s" instead of the number?

Comment: _“I have `s` from an option”_ – you mean the user choses it from a select field or something like that? Might be better to provide just a normal input field, let them type the character they want to use into that – and then fetch the keycode via a keydown handler on that input.

Comment: Per my understanding, you want to capture `ALT` + `s` keypress event.. right? If yes, you can check following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/8whsn5tk/)

Comment: @CBroe The option is stored in PHP so that might not be possible. I had in mind to create a PHP array of all the letters and the ALT numbers for it but I would prefer taking an easier approach if exists.

Comment: Yes, exists, mousetrap, but you don't want it.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property instead of `keyCode` (which is deprecated BTW)

Comment: Is requirement to call function if user presses `alt` simultaneous with `"s"` ?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, alt + s is pressed at the same time and s can be any letter so it should be converted to a number so js can understand it, or another clever solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.charCodeAt(n)` works on the character. `e.keyCode` works on the key.

`A` != `a`. But the `A` key does equal the `a` key.

```
'a'.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) // 65
'a'.charCodeAt(0)               // 97
'A'.charCodeAt(0)               // 65
'A'.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) // 97
```

Basically, you want:

```
 var _stringToKey = function() {
    string = '{{key}}';
    return parseInt( string.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) );
}
```

Comment: So how it works with a combination like `CTRL + S`? And how it works in another operating system different of Windows? And how it works in all browsers? I am interesting in that.

Comment: I explain, if you have `string = 'alt+s'`  what is the result?

Comment: It works on a PC! I tried alt + s and alt + b. Anyone want to try it out on Mac?

Comment: I have a Mac and a Linux. Remember that in Mac, Command replaces the normal CTRL in a PC.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I know, that is why I use ALT. Does it work on your Mac and Linux?

Comment: I don't know, create a fiddle where I can test and I tell you if it works.

Comment: @Jens It's quite a big subject. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give a specific answer. I'd suggest reading around the [keyDown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown). I've created a fiddle with a few different approaches [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/kzgd3vpy/1/). The third one is pasing a string like 'ctrl+alt+S' to do _something_ (in my case, setting the value of an input.) HTH!

Answer (score 0):

That you are trying exists! It calls **Mousetrap**.

https://craig.is/killing/mice

```
 Mousetrap.bind(['command+k', 'ctrl+k'], function(e) {
    highlight([11, 12, 13, 14]);
    return false;
 });
```

Simple and beautiful.

Comment: I don't want to rely on yet another JS plugin. The code of this plugin is larger than all the JS required for my site. Not an option but thanks for the idea. Someone else might use it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are hand-making this, your js code will be larger than mousetrap. But if you like to work hard mapping all your keys, follow your heart!

Comment: Maybe you think that 4KB of javascript slows your web. But I believe hardly that your future code will be larger than this and less optimized. It's your choice.

Comment: I have an answer that is 34 bytes. That beats 4kB. :)

Comment: It's not the same, and you know it... don't compare a cross-browser and complete plugin with triggers and listeners and customized maps with a simple conversion that only works in few cases. If it fits with your requirements it's fine, but sometimes it's better making a cross-browser and O.S. script to compatibilize all your users. Another thing is mousetrap is huge tested in several browsers and situations. It's not comparable. Don't beat anything